# (Begginer programmer) What is the difference between appending something to a list and inserting?

Tags: list, append, difference, concept

Given numbers [1,2,3,4} if I appended 4 what would the list now be?

Given the same list of numbers if I inserted 4 what would the result be.

Im new in programming (dont roast me lol) and am not grasping this concept yet.

Comment: list `append` is to put the new item at the very end - so you will get [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]`.

Answer (score 0):

Terms explained: `append` is putting the `new item` at the tail/end of an existing list/array.  And `insert` is to put the `new` item at specific position or `index`.   There are more info. you can read through to deepen your understanding here - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Let's have some examples to show the difference:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

x = 9

lst.append(x)    # lst becomes - [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]

y = 11
lst.insert(3, y)    # lst now is - [1, 2, 3, 11, 4, 5, 9]
```